# catching exceptions from pandas read_sql() method when connecting to AWS Athena

Tags: python, pandas, exception, amazon-athena

I have a program that I would like to make more robust.
It connects to Athena and then reads data into a pandas data frame
with read_sql() method.
I could not find the correct way to catch exceptions if something went wrong with the query and the general Exception does not do the work (please see below).
I know that I am supposed to import Athena exception module but cannot find how.
I am fine with catching any sort of Athena exception, including sql syntax, problems with db objects, data inconsistency and so on
Here is the code of my program

```
         import pyathena 
         import pandas as pd

         try:
          conn = pyathena.connect('hiding details...')
          sql = 'select * from tbl'
          df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
          print(df)
        except Exception as ex:
         do some actions
```

Comment: What do you mean that "the general Exception does not do the work"?

Comment: Do you want something like `traceback`?

Comment: I wrote a sql with a table that does not exist - expecting the Exception to catch it and give the appropriate message, but it does not.

Comment: Does the exception get thrown when you execute the query just using pyathena? As in `conn.execute(sql)`?

Comment: did not try that, but I need it to come from pandas